Is it possible to access GCP metadata endpoint from Cloud Run instance?
I have a cloud run instance that I'm trying to use to communicate with another, secured Cloud Run instance.
The latter instance allows external traffic but can only be invoked by set service accounts.
Problem is, in order for my instance to invoke via HTTPS, it needs to send a token in the request header which I need/want to retrieve from the http://metadata endpoint, however when I attempted to do this via Cloud Run it's automatically redirected to Https and thus the endpoint fails.
Is it possible to prevent this or access metadata from a CR instance? I've tried setting specify CSP rules to override but these are ignored.
Thanks in advance

The metadata server can be access only by the instance itself, not by external calls. When you invoke this metadata endpoint, be sure to add the correct header. Or, you can use the Google Cloud OAuth client libraries that get the identity token for you from the metadata server!

Can you elaborate why metadata need to be shared b/w systems? Also, I hope you have seen https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/querying-metadata

As mentioned in Metadata security considerations, any process that can query the metadata URL, has access to all values in the metadata server.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/querying-metadata explain steps to access http://metadata.goog via curl examples. In the same page, please note the required permission section to know required permissions.
